# VS 2019 with Xamarin, cant debug due to warning: Debugging symbol file is not valid and was ignored

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(373,3): warning MT0178: Debugging symbol file for '/Users/appledevelopment/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/XamAppHartzSystems.iOS/831856682f36592c89c1d1be72305370c507305528b30a6064078e5ddad8b0d1/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/XamAppHartzSystems.dll' is not valid and was ignored.

Getting this warning in my build process.  The build completes without errors.

The build is for a Xamarin iOS project that was working before I updated xcode and visual studio 19 to latest versions.

When I try to put a brakepoint in my shared library, it will not stop in the debugger due to the above warning.

I have tried to clear all the obj and bin folders, but that does not help.

I can't seem to find why it thinks the symbol file is invalid.

Windows VS is up to date
Mac xcode is up to date
Mac VS is up to date
Using Xamarin Forms 4.8.1821, tried the latest version too with no luck.

How do I find out why my symbol file is invalid...

Comment: 1) After the update, can you successfully rebuild JUST that shared library? (not your whole solution, or your main app project) 2) What happens if you delete all files in the cache folder (on your Mac) mentioned in that error message? 3) You are building in VS Windows? Do you get the same error if you build in VS Mac? (after deleting bin and obj folders there.)

Comment: Somehow in the Library Build Settings, the Debugging information was set to Pdb-only.  I changed it to Portable and it fixed the problem.

Comment: That's great!  Please add an "Answer" below (yes, you can answer your own question), so that others will know that your question has been answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Somehow in the Library Build Settings, the Debugging information was set to Pdb-only. I changed it to Portable and it fixed the problem.

It happened to a few of my projects after upgrading to the latest VS and xcode.